# How to copy code of CSS from link into file

Tags: css

I use a link in my html. How i can copy code of this file to edit it?

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to edit a minified file?

It can be done but it's difficult.

Instead, put that whole address minus the .min in your browser's address field

https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css

and you should see the code unminified which you can then copy/save to your local system for editing. (on Windows this would be by right clicking the mouse/pad).

I am not sure whether you do want to actually edit this file, or whether you want to change some of its effects. If the latter you link to the file then put your own CSS in style element following and it will overwrite with whatever settings you have given.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your custom css style after it so it will overrite it.
In main html file you can just add styles right after `<head>` for example:

```
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

      <style>
       body {
         background-color: red;
      }
    </style>
```

So what happens now it imports bootstrap styles but after that overrides it so you can add your custom styles inside `<style>`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply open the url - https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
and save (ctrl+s) the file locally in your project and include the css file path with the help of this tag given below :-

You can also use custom css and then overide the css.

(Note :- Format the document/css file then you can edit the document)